# Text process inside specific nginx block code

Tags: text-processing

When a script runs I need to convert the following block of text that remains inside. The part

```
include conf.d/includes-optional/cpanel-proxy.conf;
proxy_pass $scheme://$CPANEL_APACHE_PROXY_REQ_IP:$CPANEL_APACHE_PROXY_REQ_PORT;
```

may change so I need to to process whatever may be inside the block

```
location / {
    
}
```

Code:

```
location / {
    include conf.d/includes-optional/cpanel-proxy.conf;
    proxy_pass $scheme://$CPANEL_APACHE_PROXY_REQ_IP:$CPANEL_APACHE_PROXY_REQ_PORT;
}
```

into

```
location / {
    limit_req zone=foo burst=300 nodelay;
    limit_conn addr 1;
    limit_rate 200k;
    include conf.d/includes-optional/cpanel-proxy.conf;
    proxy_pass $scheme://$CPANEL_APACHE_PROXY_REQ_IP:$CPANEL_APACHE_PROXY_REQ_PORT;
}
    
limit_req_status 429;
limit_conn_status 429;
    
error_page 429 /429.html;
location = /429.html {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    internal;
}
```

Comment: So basically, you want to add the `limit_**` statements into the curly braces started on a line `location /`, and before any text that is already inside these braces. Is that right?

Comment: Yes and after the first set of brackets the ```limit_req_status 429``` and ```error_page 429 /429.html``` part

Comment: Ok, then please rephrase your question to make that point clearer; it will help contributors provide more suitable answers to your question.

Comment: What is the context of this? Are you doing this as a one-time text editing job, because you have a large number of similar such `location` blocks in many files? Or will this be an ongoing transformation, where those files are regularly changing, and the edited versions have to update?